# Can a workplace ask for Power of Attorney?

Tags: human-resources, intellectual-property

A small company in the USA updated the "Employee Confidentiality Agreement and Intellectual Property Agreement" and is asking employees to sign it.

Under the heading "Assignment of Intellectual Property", they ask employees to "irrevocably grant CORPORATION'S NAME power of attorney to execute and deliver such documents... and to do all other lawfully permitted acts..."

The way I understand the word *documents* above is with respect to intellectual property, but that's just my understanding.

**The question**: is it okay to ask for power of attorney? I thought that was a pretty special thing that you don't give anyone but your spouse and your actual attorney.

Asking for a friend.

Comment: Certainly it's okay to ask.  Only the text of the document and a qualified attorney could determine if it's *wise* to comply.  Power of attorney can be given for very specific tasks.

Comment: How much extra are they offering for signing that new contract? Also, how long is the "Employee Confidentiality Agreement" supposed to last? Is it supposed to last indefinitely? Is the entire contract as broad and as vague as it sounds from your snippets? Personally, I wouldn't sign such a document.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised by this for a company that creates new novel intellectual property to manage.  If there are patents to be applied for you don't want to be the one dealing with all the legal paperwork, but if it's your research, your name will be on it , so they need permission.

Comment: @cdkMoose That is correct, and it makes my friend feel a lot better about the clause.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk From what I understand, it lasts indefinitely, and yes, it is fairly vague.   Hence my friend feeling a bit leery.

Comment: Power can be conditional or time-limited. You need legal advice which would be beyond our scope here.

Answer (score 5):

Power of attorney can be as general or as specific as desired, depending on exactly how the document is worded. This *could* be legitimate for some highly unusual business reason.

But caution is certainly warranted. This is not a common request. I would be very skeptical that it was really the right way to address the business's needs.

I would ***highly*** recommend getting your own lawyer to review it for hazards before signing,

Comment: For what it's worth, my employer simply wrote into the contract that all intellectual property in the company's fields of interest produced during the time of employment were the company's property ("works for hire") unless the company explicitly said otherwise, with an accompanying policy that specifically exempted open-source participation that wasn't in direct competition with the company's business. No power of attorney needed since the agreement was already in place. This might not be possible in all countries or all businesses, admittedly.